# Turning Http server written in C into HTTPS using RSA

Tags: c, http, https, server, rsa

I have built a server in *C* from sratch using sockets and I was wandering if it is possible for me to add an extra layer of security by adding *RSA* encryption to make sure that the client and the server have a encrypted communication.

I am quite familiar with the theory behind *RSA*, and I have built the encryption tool before and succesfully was able to encrypt keys. I was just wondering I could include this in my C server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's a lot more to TLS -- that is, Transport-Level Security, which is used to implement HTTPS -- than RSA encryption.

Your best bet will be to integrate the OpenSSL library, which implements TLS. Otherwise, you will have a number of major hurdles to overcome, including:

- Parsing the TLS message format
- Parsing X.509 certificates and validating the certificate chain
- Performing a TLS handshake, which requires:

  - Implementing one or more key exchange algorithms (like RSA-DSS)
  - Implementing one or more encryption suites (like AES-CBC)
  - Implementing one or more data integrity suites (like SHA256)
  - Implementing workarounds for known errata of other TLS implementations

Comment: And here I was thinking this question was too broad. That's about as good an answer as could be found.